# How to check if system tray already exists in Java

Tags: java, awt

Is there any way that I can check if a system tray already exists? When I keep running the program to create a system tray then multiple occurrences appear, which means multiple programs are running. So, I need to check the system tray is already there?

Comment: What's a *system tray*? Also keep in mind that you need to add `System.exit(0);` at the end of main in some programs that do not auto terminate.

Comment: I add my program details to the windows system tray. But when i go to another jFrame and come back to main jFrame another system tray will appear.

Comment: Just to check you are talking about this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html so you have multiple application which can add to this systry ?

Comment: Yes I have. But this is not working. I tried.

Comment: Shell_NotifyIconGetRect() may help if you gave your icon a GUID. This is plain win32, but there must be a way in Java to invoke native functions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicongetrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Check the tray content through multiple running applications

You cannot as `SystemTray` methods refer to the `SystemTray` of the current application.
So distinct applications don't share the same `SystemTray` state.

The `SystemTray` javadoc states indeed :

> Every Java application has a single SystemTray instance that allows
>   the app to interface with the system tray of the desktop while the app
>   is running.

As a general way, multiple running JVMs should be isolated between them.
So your requirement should probably not be solved by coupling them.
If you run multiple times the same application, you should accept that each one has exactly the same behavior.
On the contrary, if you don't want to allow to run concurrently multiple times the same application, you could use a trick as opening a `ServerSocket` connection [on a specific port at the application startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036108/prevent-launching-multiple-instances-of-a-java-application).

#### Check the tray content  inside one running application

You can by using `SystemTray.getTrayIcons()` that returns the actual  icons added to the tray by the application in a `TrayIcon[]` object.
You can so iterate on array elements and add the `TrayIcon` only if you found no match.

Additionally note that if you add twice the same `TrayIcon` instance, an `IllegalArgumentException` should be thrown according to the `SystemTray.add()` method :

```
else if (icons.contains(trayIcon)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("adding TrayIcon that is already added");    
}
```

Comment: How can I check it using if condition?

Comment: Yes sure. Can you post it?

Comment: @Hansana Athukorala In fact checking the tray content through multiple running applications is not possible. I updated to differentiate two cases.