# How to detect if tray already running or disabling for running more then once

Tags: java, system, tray

I created a TrayIcon via java.
But I have a problem that if you run the runable jar file its creating again the same tray.
Is there a way to disable it to open only one tray?
Or to check if the tray already exist and by that not running the tray?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent launching multiple instances of a java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036108/prevent-launching-multiple-instances-of-a-java-application)

Answer (score 0):

Runing multiple times the jar means starting multiple applications (and JVM) and every Java application has a single `SystemTray` instance.
From `SystemTray` javadoc :

> Every Java application has a single SystemTray instance that allows
>   the app to interface with the system tray of the desktop while the app
>   is running. T

So you should use a home strategy to detect if the application is already run or more simply prevent the application to run more than once.
Creating a server socket, bounds to a specific port (with a `ServerSocket` instance for example) as the application starts is a simple way to do that.
Here is an example with a exception thrown as detected :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
    assertNoOtherInstanceRunning();
    ...     // application code then        
}

public static void assertNoOtherInstanceRunning() {       
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            new ServerSocket(9000).accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("the application is probably already started", e);
        }
    }).start();       
}
```

Comment: ok thank you. I didn't know how to do it with the serversocket but now with your example I am.

Comment: Now after massing around with it, it still doesn't work.
When I run the program on the theerd time it still executing it with no problem although I using the detection

Comment: @user5327287 My bad. Forget to `bind()` Note that the method blocks, so using  a thread makes sense to not block the Main thread.