# Bring a running application to front when other instance is opened

Tags: java, desktop-application

I have made my java application as Single instance application. I have implemented File Lock system for the same.

If the application is already running, I want to show the running application to front. How do I achieve that? How can I acess the running process of that application and show it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict multiple instances of an application in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134694/restrict-multiple-instances-of-an-application-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is OS dependent but you can always have your own implementation to do this. You application can listen on a certain port for a `bring-to-front` command that you can send from the second instance of your application.

```
void main(String[] args){
   if(applicationAlreadyRunning){
     // Send bring-to-front message to running instance on a known port
     // and exit.
   }
}
```

When a bring-to-front message is received you can do:

```
public void BringToFrontCommandReceived(){
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myMainFrame.toFront();
                    myMainFrame.repaint();
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: *"listen on a certain port"*  Of course, if using sockets for 'to front', you might also drop the entire file lock and simply check for a listener on that port as the 'have I already run?' check.

Answer (score 1):

[JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) not only provides an x-plat [`SingleInstanceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceService.html), but it also (from memory) pops the application [`toFront()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toFront%28%29) on [`newActivation(String[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceListener.html#newActivation%28java.lang.String[]%29).  Of course if it is not automatic, you can call it explicitly.

Here is a [demo. of the SIS](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#sis).