# JFrame transition effect - when called setState(Frame.ICONIFIED) it just goes to Taskbar without animation

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a problem now - when I call `frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED)` with my custom button (I'm not using default JFrame minimize button - JFrame set to `setUndecorated(true)` ), the JFrame just goes to Taskbar without any animation. In normal situation it should gradually go to Taskbar minimizing itself. But if I press iconfied JFrame on Taskbar, it restores with animation to normal size. The situation is on Windows XP, not tested on other systems, but I suppose it would behave in the same way.

Comment: :-)  [frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.ICONIFIED); and tpogether with                frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() & (~JFrame.ICONIFIED));](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6139696/714968)

Comment: But it must be platform independent.. Maybe simpler solution would be to make `JWindow`, and by pressing on some button, it would minimize to taskbar like decorated `JFrame`? I do not need any of `JFrame` methods.

Comment: is JWindow visible in task panel, or task manager (Window OS) not, then you have to use JDialog as switch for JWindow, then is traced in task panel ..... by window(state)Listener or ??? :-)

Comment: See https://github.com/kalibetre/CustomDecoratedJFrame
It fixed the problem for Swing (JFrame) and also for [Compose Multiplatform](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform). May be applied to JavaFX too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you are saying is true, and your undecorated windows do in fact animate when clicking the icons in the task bar. Then you can trigger that same action in your code using JNA.

For this solution to work, you'll need to include [jna.jar](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/dist/jna.jar?raw=true) and [jna-platform.jar](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/dist/jna-platform.jar?raw=true) in your classpath.

This isn't a JNA tutorial, there are plenty of those around. This is just code that uses JNA to call the user32.dll functions [CloseWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [OpenIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); These are the functions that Windows calls when you click the application's tray icon -- *(truth be told I'm not certain that these are the actual functions, but they react the same)*.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Window;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;

public class IconifyUtilityClass
{
    public static void minimize(Window window)
    {
        HWND hWnd = getHWND(window);
        User32dll.INSTANCE.CloseWindow(hWnd); //call CloseWindow with this windows handle
    }

    public static void restore(Window window)
    {
        HWND hWnd = getHWND(window);
        User32dll.INSTANCE.OpenIcon(hWnd); //call OpenIcon with this windows handle
    }

    private interface User32dll extends Library
    {
        User32dll INSTANCE = (User32dll) Native.loadLibrary("user32.dll", User32dll.class);
        boolean OpenIcon(HWND hWnd);
        boolean CloseWindow(HWND hWnd);
    }

    private static HWND getHWND(Component comp)
    {
        return new HWND(Native.getComponentPointer(comp));
    }
}
```

To call the code just pass in your frame or dialog like so

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
...
IconifyUtilityClass.minimize(frame); //minimize your frame
...
IconifyUtilityClass.restore(frame); //restore your frame
```

---

It's worth noting that in Windows 7 undecorated frames don't animate at all (even using the user32.dll [AnimateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function). So if your goal is to get your frames to animate anywhere, you are right, you'll have to do it yourself. JavaFx has some really nice animation stuff that would help with this.

Comment: Accepted this answer :), but I still not satisfied - will continue to look for solutions how to make window behave the same on various platforms. I think it is OK if the frame is not animated at all, even when clicking on taskbar when it backs. It should be animated or not at all. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you want it to be platform independent, my other answer will not work for you. Also, each platform will react differently when you minimize or hide a window. You mentioned it would be nice to see a Java code fragment that would give you a consistent animation. Here's some code for you.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FadeUtilityClass
{
    private static final int TIME = 200;
    private static final int MILLIS_PER_FRAME = 33;
    private static final float DELTA = MILLIS_PER_FRAME / (float)TIME; //how much the opacity will change on each tick

    /**
     * @param frame the frame to fade in or out
     * @param in true if you are fading in, false if you're fading out
     */
    public static void fade(final JFrame frame, final boolean in)
    {
        frame.setOpacity(in ? 0f : 1f); //if we're fading in, make sure our opacity is 0, and 1 if we're fading out
        if (in) //set the state back to normal because we might have been minimized
            frame.setState(JFrame.NORMAL); 
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
        {
            float opacity = in ? 0f : 1f;
            float delta = in ? DELTA : -DELTA;

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                opacity += delta; //tweak the opacity
                if (opacity < 0) //we're invisible now
                {
                    frame.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED); //hide frame
                    frame.setOpacity(1f); //then make it opaque again, so it'll reappear properly if they click the taskbar 
                    timer.cancel(); //stop the timer
                }
                else if (opacity > 1) //we're fully visible now
                {
                    frame.setOpacity(1f); //make the opacity an even 1.0f
                    timer.cancel(); //stop the timer
                }
                else
                    frame.setOpacity(opacity);
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, MILLIS_PER_FRAME, MILLIS_PER_FRAME);
    }
}
```

It's a utility class that will make your undecorated frame fade in or out. Since the location of the taskbar and minimized window changes based on the platform and you would need to use platform specific api's to find that, I just made the animation fade the window out without shrinking it down to where the taskbar *might* be.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

by calling

```
myJFrame.setUndecorated( true )
```

You're disabling any frame decorations for your JFrame.
This includes the animations on maximizing and minimizing your JFrame.

If you skip this call or change it to

```
myJFrame.setUndecorated( false )
```

then the animations will be visible again, even by minimizing the frame with a call to

```
myJFrame.setState( Frame.ICONIFIED );
```

AFAIK, there is no way to animate an undecorated frame. :(

Please find my full code sample here:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize( 800, 600 );
    frame.setUndecorated( false );  // will enable animations
    frame.setVisible( true );
    try { Thread.sleep( 3000 ); } catch ( Throwable t ) {}
    frame.setState( Frame.ICONIFIED );
```

Greetings

Christopher

Comment: But how to explain that - if the frame is `setUndecorated(true)`, and if I minimize it - it goes without animation to taskbar, AND THEN if I click it on taskbar, it backs WITH animation..

Comment: Hmm., I think I must create some custom animation, which behave like the original one. It would be nice to see Java code fragment which do that animation - will try to find.

Comment: Sorry. I can't reproduce this. If setUndecorated( true ) is set, the window is minimized without animation and it is restored or maximized without any animation. ( Windows 7 )

Comment: You shouldn't overestimate these window-animations.. Users are also able to disable them in the system settings of their os. This behaviour should not be overridden. Greetings

Comment: You mean when `frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);` ? If so, yes, it restored without animation. BUT if I press the button on PC taskbar, then it backs with animation..