# Minimize animation for windows 8 on javafx app

Tags: java, windows, animation, javafx, minimize

How do I apply the minimize animation of a program when it minimizes on windows 8? My application has the stage.setIconified(true) but the program simply disappears from the screen without any animations. In windows 8, any app that you minimize performs an animation before it minimizes, same is through when reopening/maximizing it.

Comment: I think this an OS issue on my mac when I setIconified to true it does the animation

Comment: I see. I could try replecating it, but I was wondering if there was some sort of library provided by windows for devs...no?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761134/jframe-transition-effect-when-called-setstateframe-iconified-it-just-goes-to